# Show Post ID in "Find Posts or Pages" box in Media Library?

Tags: attachments, media-library

In the Media Library, when I go in to attach a media item to a post, I know I can use "Attach" to pull up the "Find Posts or Pages" pop up.

This brings the following list of post title, date and status.
[image: find posts or pages results]

I wonder if there is a way to have the results show the post ID as well?

It might have something to do with the `find_posts_div` function, but I'm not sure how to apply the proper filters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do that with pure PHP. The table is created in `wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php::wp_ajax_find_posts()`, and there is no filter.

But look at the radio buttons:

```
name="found_post_id" value="' . esc_attr($post->ID)
```

You can print a script on the action `admin_footer-upload.php` that extracts the post ID from the values and adds a new column to the table.

Here is a working example as a plugin. The code is not exactly beautiful, but it works and it should speak for itself:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Extend Media Find Posts Table
 */

add_action( 'admin_footer-upload.php', 't5_add_id_to_post_search' );

function t5_add_id_to_post_search()
{
?>
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    // bind ajaxStop() to any unique element.
    $('#find-posts-submit').ajaxStop(function() {
        var table = $('#find-posts-response table');
        // add the heading
        $(table).find('thead tr').append($('<th>ID</th>').css('width', '2em'));
        // take ID from input and append as 'td'
        $(table).find('tbody tr').each(function(){
            $(this).append('<td>' + $(this).find('input').val() + '</td>');
        });
    });
});
</script>
<?php
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, toscho. But I can't seem to hook into the content inside of this "found-posts" div. I've tried adding some echo statements to test, but nothing will show up. Any ideas?

Comment: See my update. Tested, works. :)